# query with php array in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to fetch contents with multiple filters, right now there's only one. 
For Example:

> SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE status=true AND category = 'Camera' AND
>   model = 'Samsung' AND type = 'New'

I want to create an array for it. But as I'm a newbie in this one not getting a lead.

```
function getAllRequests($filter){
if(empty($filter)){
    $addfilter = '';    
    }else{
    $addfilter = 'AND cat_id=' . $filter;
    }
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE status=true' . $filter;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you closer to the solution, though it will not replace the `cat_id` in the query, which will certainly be wrong - though impossible to do too much more without the array structure:

```
function getAllRequests($filter)
{
    $addfilter="";
    if(!empty($filter))
    {
        foreach($filter as $val)
        {
            $addfilter. = ' AND cat_id=' . $val .'\'';
        }
    }
    return $addFilter;
}

$myFilters=getAllRequests($filter);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE status=true' . $myFilters;
```

On the other hand, if your array is strucutred in a way like this:

```
array{ category => camera, model => samsung); // etc
```

you could use the following:

```
function getAllRequests($filter)
{
    $addfilter="";
    if(!empty($filter))
    {
        foreach($filter as $key => $val)
        {
            $addfilter. = " AND `$key` = '$val'";
        }
    }
    return $addFilter;
}

$myFilters=getAllRequests($filter);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE status=true' . $myFilters;
```

Edit: You can loop through all the filters in the following manner:

```
function getAllRequests()
{
    $addfilter="";
    if(!empty($_REQUEST))
    {
    foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $val)
    {
        $addfilter. = " AND `$key` = '$val'";
    }
    }
    return $addFilter;
}

$myFilters=getAllRequests();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE status=true' . $myFilters;
```

You don't need to pass the `$_REQUEST` (which will work for both GET and POST) as it already a superglobal.

Comment: @Fluffeh- like your idea can you help me to create an array from my url? as all my filters are in url example: get.php?type=car&year=2012&color=black ... thx

Answer (score 1):

```
function getAllRequests($filter){
if(empty($filter)){
$addfilter = '';    
}else{
$addfilter = 'AND cat_id=' . $filter;
 }
}
```

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE status=true' . $addfilter;

Answer (score 0):

You can use another approach, which is using optional parameters and it will make your `WHERE` clause dynamic as you want. In this approach you pass all parameters' values directly to the sql query which should look like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (@status   IS NULL OR status   = @statusParam)
  AND (@category IS NULL OR category = @categoryParam)
  AND (@model    IS NULL OR model    = @modelParam)
  AND (@type     IS NULL OR type     = @typeParam)
```

Then If any of the parameters `@statusParam`, `@categoryParam`, `@modelParam` or `@typeParam` passed to the query with `NULL` values, then the comparison with the column holding that value will be ignored. I used the predicate `1 = 1`, in case all the values passed to the query with all `NULL` values in the case all the `WHERE` clause will be ignored as it won't presented, since `WHERE 1 = 1` always true and it will be like `SELECT * FROM Table1`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function getAllRequests($filter){
    if(empty($filter)){
      $addfilter = '';    
     }else{
      $addfilter .= 'AND cat_id=' . $filter;
    }
  return $addfilter;
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE status=true' . getAllRequests($filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending array make sure it has indexes

```
 $conditions = array('category' => 'Camera', 'model' => 'Samsung' , 'type' => 'New')
```

Now loop through it. in your else condition

```
foreach($conditions as $key =>$value){

    $addfilter .= 'AND ' . $key . ' = ' . $value;

}
```